# How can I receive FCM when my app is not running?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to receive the notification when my application is not running.

I could receive the notification when my application is on foreground or background and I could handle it. But, when my application is not running, I can't receive the notification and also not appear banner as well.

I'm doing like this `https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/FCMSwift/AppDelegate.swift`.
And I also set push notification -> on, background modes -> on and remote notifications is checked in my setting file.

How can I receive the notification? Anyone help?

Comment: Can you post your payload?

Comment: @intj no, I can't.